# Conditional ng-model binding in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a model which is an array that needs to handle complex and simple elements :

```
{
    "object" :[
               "element1.html",
               "element2.html",
               {
                   "url:"element3.html",
                   "title" : "Title 3"
               },
               "element4.html",
               "element5.html"
            ]
}
```

Is there some way to make a select which can handle both simple and complex elements in angularjs (showing url from the complexs)?

**Approach 1**

I mean some like that:

```
ng-model="(object[$index].url ? object[$index].url : object[$index])"
```

**Approach 2**

Make a normalized object that will have the complex structure for each object with empty arrays and a file type indicating whether is simple or complex.

Could I make some magic with angular to avoid the second approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

You could use `ngSwitch` or `ngIf` and place the correct element then.

With ngIf for example:

```
<input ngIf="object[$index].url" ngModel="object[$index].url">
<input ngIf="!object[$index].url" ngModel="object[$index]">
```

If the condition is not met, angular will completely remove the dom element, till the condition will meet.

Comment: Looks like your conditions are mixed up.

Answer (score 15):

### Using getters and setters

You can define getters and setters on an object and [put logic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93183/logic-in-setters-vs-getters) in it to retrieve/set whatever other object you wanted to get/modify conditionally.

[Angular has a `ng-model-options="{getterSetter:true}"`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel#binding-to-a-getter-setter)  which you can use as follows:

```
input(ng-model="data" ng-model-options="{getterSetter:true}")
```

```
var data1 = "data 1";
var data2 = "data 2";
$scope.data = function(newVal) {
    if (condition) {
        if (angular.isDefined(newVal))
            data1 = newVal;
        return data1;
    } else {
        if (angular.isDefined(newVal))
            data2 = newVal;
        return data2;
    }
};
```

However, and this might be just in my case, it alone didn't work or not as expected.

There's also the JavaScript's default way to do the same using `Object.defineProperty`

```
var data1 = "data 1";
var data2 = "data 2";
Object.defineProperty($scope, 'data', {
    get: function() {
        if(condition)
            return data1;
        else
            return data2;
    },
    set: function(newVal) {
        if(condition)
            data1 = newVal;
        else
            data2 = newVal;
    }
});
```

Again, this might be just in my case, but using only either of them alone didn't work or didn't work as expected. So I used them both together and it works perfectly.

Comment: It would be really helpful if there were a getterSetter option for binding models to directives (in a two way data binding) and not just fields which take an ng-model.