# How to use ng-model with checkbox value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-model

I want to this :

Summary Row should be checked/unchecked for datetime and object at once as well as separately. my display like photo : [image]

I use ng-model. my checkbox code as the following :

```
 <div class='ui-widget-header ui-corner-all pw-chart-header' style="padding-left:12px ">
                                            <input type="checkbox" value="3" style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 0" id="selectsummarizationType" ng-model="summarizationtypeBoth" btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="true" btn-checkbox-false="false" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"> Summary Row
                                        </div>


      <div style="padding-top:10px ; padding-bottom:10px; padding-left:10px ; padding-right:10px">
                                                   <label for="uxDatetime">
                                                     <input type="checkbox" value="1" style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 0" id="uxDatetime" name="uxDatetime" ng-model="summarizationtypeDate" btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="true" btn-checkbox-false="false" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"> Datetime
                                                   </label>
                                                   <label for="uxObject" style="float: right">
                                                     <input type="checkbox" value="2" style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 0" id="uxObject"  name="uxObject" ng-model="summarizationtypeObject" btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="true" btn-checkbox-false="false" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"> Object
                                                   </label>
                                                </div>
```

and this is ng-model (js) code :

```
$scope.$watch('summarizationtypeBoth', function () {

                });
                $scope.$watch('summarizationtypeDate', function () {

                });
                $scope.$watch('summarizationtypeObject', function () {

                });
```

how can I use ng-model so How do I write ?
Please.

Comment: put ng-change on summary input and set the other two.

Comment: if i understood your problem check this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/wYmWXnu5Ld2SmUdGayfd?p=preview

Comment: I think this help me but How can I do :  put ng-change on summary input and set the other two.By the way Thank you for your answer  @YOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Us ng-change property :

```
<input type="checkbox" value="3" style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 0" id="selectsummarizationType" ng-model="summarizationtypeBoth" btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="true" btn-checkbox-false="false" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-change="summaryChecked()"> Summary Row
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.summaryChecked = function() { 
   $scope.summarizationtypeDate = $scope.summarizationtypeBoth
   $scope.summarizationtypeObject= $scope.summarizationtypeBoth
}
```

See this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/ztL4nC6JYDv1lpnuMr4s?p=preview

Comment: I did but nothing to do. maybe this cause: my ng-models are empty ? @Silvinus

Comment: In this case, add this after your your input :
{{summarizationtypeBoth}} - {{summarizationtypeDate}} - {{summarizationtypeObject}}

abd check when you check first the value of summarizationtypeBoth change.

Comment: I dont understand. What do you mean ? @Silvinus

Comment: Just add in your hml page '{{summarizationtypeBoth}} - {{summarizationtypeDate}} - {{summarizationtypeObject}}'.
This will be displayed the value of this scope properties.
Is just to check if your properties are correctly bind on scope

Comment: when i check summarizationtypeBoth Output : true - true - true . @Silvinus

Comment: And your checkbox are checked ?

And what is your output when you uncheck summarizationtypeBoth ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid `$scope.$watch` as much as possible because it may slow your web application.

You should use an object with the 3 values and using getters and setters to ensure your conditions. There is an exemple here :[Conditional ng-model binding in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23107788/conditional-ng-model-binding-in-angularjs)

With `ng-model-options`, you can force to call your setters : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Comment: I am working learn angularjs so I am new this stuff. so I'm not sure how the code may cast. Can you make examples out of question @Thibault Friedrich